# Firestore snapshot listener limit per client. Does a single client encompass all instances of the app running on the browser?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase defines in their best-practices page that each client should not use more than a 100 snapshot document listeners for performance reasons.

This may come off as a really silly question, but what do they mean with "Client"? Are all instances of the app running on a browser (multiple tabs) considered a single "Client" or is each tab considered it own "Client"?

[Link for reference]
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#:~:text=For%20best%20performance%2C%20snapshot%20listeners,may%20be%20happening%20too%20frequently.&text=Keep%20the%20number%20of%20snapshot%20listeners%20per%20client%20under%20100](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#:%7E:text=For%20best%20performance%2C%20snapshot%20listeners,may%20be%20happening%20too%20frequently.&text=Keep%20the%20number%20of%20snapshot%20listeners%20per%20client%20under%20100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think each tab is considered a independent client. Listeners are used to be placed in frontend, every tab can run it's own code executing the listener object.

Comment: It's the "I think" part that worries me because some of my colleagues agree with you and some don't but the thing they have in common is that they are not 100% sure

Comment: But I do think you are right.